# How to only execute code after 5 seconds?

Tags: unity-game-engine, wait, unityscript

So, in Unity I have this Hunger code that subtracts a little each time.

```js
#pragma strict

var Hunger:float;
var MaxHunger:float=100;
var timer:float;

function Start () 
{
    Hunger=MaxHunger;
}

function Update () 
{
    timer+=Time.deltaTime;
    if(timer>=10) 
    {
    Hunger-=1.0;
    }
}
```

My problem is that I only want 1 to be subtracted from Hunger every five seconds. I already tried setting it to take off 0.2 every second, but it doesn't work. I just need it to wait for five seconds before subtracting 1. Thanks!

Comment: Use javascript "setInterval" function. Here is a link to instructions. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: @KentAnderson Take a look at [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/). And this is the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) mdn doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [InvokeRepeating](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) method:

```js
function SubtractHunger ()
{
    Hunger -= 1.0;
}

function Start () {
    Hunger = MaxHunger;
    var seconds:int = 5;
    InvokeRepeating("SubtractHunger", seconds, seconds);
}

// and then you don't need the Update function
```

---

Or, you could use a `timeLastSubtracted` variable or similar to check within your `Update` function:

```js
var timeLastSubtracted:float;

function Update ()
{
    if (Time.time >= timeLastSubtracted + 5) {
        Hunger -= 1.0;
        timeLastSubtracted = Time.time;
    }
}
```